# How to scroll through questions in an object array by clicking?

Tags: javascript, object, scroll, onclick

```
let questions = {
    question1: "This is the first question",
    question2: "And this is the second",
    question3: "Another one"
}



for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(questions)){

    document.addEventListener("click", () => document.write(value));
}
```

Comment: i dont know what you want from us. could you clarify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to show questions order by order when user click somewhere on the window.

```
let questions = {
    question1: "This is the first question",
    question2: "And this is the second",
    question3: "Another one"
}

const questionsArray = Object.values(questions);
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
   document.write(questionsArray.shift());
})
```